# JButtons acting weird after adding getter

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I'm making a java game that has an array of JButtons in a JPanel.
Everything is working fine, except when I add a simple getter to my extended JButton class.
What's happening is that the JButtons are only visible, when I hover over them.
If I just remove the getter, the problem does not occur anymore.
Why is that happening, how can I solve that?

```
public class MyButton extends JButton {

int x;
int y;

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
}

public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}
```

}

Comment: Don't override the getX() and getY() methods. Those methods already exist in the API. Give your variables and methods a different name. Looks to me like you are probably trying to give the button a position on a grid so try using names like "row, column" and "getRow(), getColumn()".

Comment: To extend on what @camickr said, don't extend components (containers or windows) without good reason. It seems everything this extension achieves could be better replicated in `JButton[][]`. Having said that, I'm not entirely sure of what this extension is *supposed* to achieve. So YMMV.

Comment: @camickr that solved my Problem. Can you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Everything is working fine, except when I add a simple getter to my extended JButton class

Don't override the getX() and getY() methods. Those methods already exist in the API. Give your variables and methods a different name.

> I'm making a java game that has an array of JButtons in a JPanel

You are probably trying to give the button a position on a grid so try using:

1. variable names like `row` and `column`
2. method names like `getRow()` and `getColumn()`